# Partial C++ Template Specialization with STL containers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

So my goal is to create a function or functor that can return different values. The use case is to convert Json objects into the correct C++ type. For the most part I have this working but I'm running into issues with containers such as `std::vector` and `std::array`. I know you can't overload a function to just return different value types so I've been using a `struct` with template specialization. I figured I would need to use partial template specialization to achieve this but I'm running into compile errors. Here's what my code looks like:

```
template <typename T>
struct from_json
{
    T operator()(const Json::Value &json)
    {
        return T::fromJson(json);
    }
};

template <>
struct from_json<std::string>
{
    std::string operator()(const Json::Value &json)
    {
        return std::string(json.asCString());
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct from_json<std::vector<T> >
{
    std::vector<T> operator()(const Json::Value &json)
    {
        std::vector<T> vector;

        for (auto obj : json)
            vector.push_back(from_json(obj));

        return vector;
    }
};
```

Some notes on the code snippet:
I have an abstract class that requires `fromJson` to be implemented by my own serializable classes which is what the general case is about. The `std::string` generalization seems to work fine. The `std::vector` is where things break. The compiler recognizes that that is the specialization that should be used but gives an error when trying to actually use it.

```
std::vector<std::string> my_vector = from_json<std::vector<std::string> >(json["my_vector"]);
```

The compiler error is the following:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'from_json<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::from_json(const Json::Value&)'
std::vector<std::string> my_vector = from_json<std::vector<std::string> >(json["my_vector"]);
note: candidate: constexpr from_json<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::from_json()
```

It is also worth noting that I am using C++ 11.

I'm definitely open to suggestions on this could be done better if there is a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in this line:

```
vector.push_back(from_json(obj));
```

`from_json` in your code is a class template with a defined `operator()`. It's not a function or a function object (in that sense, it's kind of like `std::hash`). So you can't *call* it - you need call an instantiation of it.

I'm guessing you mean something like:

```
vector.push_back(from_json<T>{}(obj));
```

Or if you're into range-v3:

```
std::vector<T> operator()(const Json::Value &json)
{
    return json | view::transform(from_json<T>{});
}
```

Comment: Wow yeah I completely messed up on the instance thing. Forgot to add the `{}` to instantiate like you suggested. Thanks for pointing that one out!